# Android - Textview in Listview updated by onItemClick, changes on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have a listview of items (ItemSong) , which when clicked start downloading (using Asynctask). I have a textview that shows the download progress.

ItemSong has an int property (percentCompleted) that tracks the download progress. DownloadTask updates this int. So this way, when I scroll back to the item, the progress is shown. But it doesn't continuously update even though the DownloadTask is running and the percentCompleted is being updated.

Everything works fine, but when I scroll down and back i.e. item is recycled, the progress stops updating. It shows the last updated valueonly when I scroll away and back to the item.

I have trimmed the code to the necessary parts, but if something is unclear I add more or explain it.

Any suggestions on what I could, even if I need to change the whole approach, is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class ItemSong implements Item{

    public final String track_name;
    public final String album_name;
    public final String track_num;
    public final String album_id;
    public final String album_link;

    private int percentCompleted = 0;

    private boolean activeDownload; //false by default

    public ItemSong(String track_name, String album_name, String track_num, String album_id, String album_link) {
        this.track_name = track_name;
        this.album_name = album_name;
        this.track_num = track_num;
        this.album_id = album_id;
        this.album_link = album_link;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return false;
    }

    public String itemType() {
        return "song";
    }

    public void setCompleted(int percent){ percentCompleted = percent; }

    public int getCompleted() {return percentCompleted;}

    public void setDownloadStatus(boolean status) {activeDownload = status;}

    public boolean downloadStatus() {return activeDownload;}

}
```

My **getView()** in the Adapter class:
I have a set a flag that updates the textview is the download is active. However this causes the app to freeze.

```
TextView percentCompleted = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.completed);

while (itemSong.downloadStatus() == true)
{
    percentCompleted.setText(Integer.toString(itemSong.getCompleted() ) );}
```

**onItemClick in my MainActivity**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {


    ItemSong itemSong = (ItemSong) items.get(position);

    TextView percentCompleted = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.completed);

    new DownloadTask(percentCompleted, itemSong).execute();


}
```

**The DownloadTask class:**

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private TextView percentComplete;
    private int prog=0;
    private ItemSong itemSong;

    DownloadTask(TextView percentComplete, ItemSong itemSong){

        this.percentComplete = percentComplete;
        this.itemSong = itemSong;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

        itemSong.setDownloadStatus(true);

        while (prog <= 100) {

            itemSong.setCompleted(prog);

            publishProgress("" + (prog));

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            prog = prog+10;
        }
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        percentComplete.setText(progress[0].toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        itemSong.setDownloadStatus(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should implement a hashMap<int,int> to store on progress item positions and progress value and in getView method of list adapter set real values after recycling

Comment: So you are saying, have the progress linked to the item position using a hashmap, so when the view is recycled in getView, the progress shows up?
I've already got that covered because the progress value is stored as part of the item property. So when the view is recycled, the progress shows up. But it doesn't continue to update unless the view recycled again.
Example: Download starts and I see the progress fine. 5-10-etc. I scroll down and progress increases to 20%. I scroll up, I see 20% but then the progress doesn't update anymore, unless I scroll down and back up.

Comment: did you call notifydatasetchanged() after progress update?

Comment: Why did you added Thread.sleep(500);?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari so that the view recycles every 1/2 sec but I wasn't thinking straight. I see that makes no sense. I'll remove it.

Comment: @bryanc Didn't think of that. Let me try that. Will calling notifydatasetchanged() too frequently cause issues?

Comment: Where are you setting setDownloadStatus() to true ?

Comment: You can use notifydataSetChanged() but that will recycle your views very frequently. You can avoid that by not showing the percent values in your list items. Instead show "Downloading....  ". This will let you recycle your views very less times as compared to showing percentage values.

Comment: i had some problem like you but i added a hashmap and after updating values called notifydatasetChanged()  it resolved mine .i dont think it causes problems except a little work for rerendering list view

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I had removed the setDownloadStatus() to true before the copying the code over. But i ran it with it in there. Re-added it to the post now.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Yeah I'm afraid of recycling the views too much, because the file progress will be updated a lot. I like the suggestion of just showing downloading if the constant recycling is too heavy. Thanks.

Comment: @bryanc Like you said, I added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to the DownloadTask after itemSong.setCompleted(prog). But that makes the app crash. I get an error: "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: It must be called in main thread in "onprogressupdate" after setting textview,s text

Comment: @bryanc Haha! That's the sound of success :) Thanks that worked perfectly. It's not causing any issues due to the recycling so far. Do you want to post this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Im glad it was in my country at 4:30 am and i fell asleep!!and yeah will post my answer

Comment: For download use android Download Manager instead. Which will start all your download at background automatically, you can also keep track of the progress using download request code, like item1 or item2 from listview. Better choice than Asynctask.

Comment: @HourGlass I was initially using DownloadManager. Why is it a better choice than using AsyncTask?

Comment: Because if your download is large or small, your asyn task will through an memory out of exception easily. whereas if you use download manager, you can download a larage file download flawlessly.. experience @fractal5

Comment: @HourGlass Hmm I didn't know that. My files are around 3-6 MB in size. Definitely less than 10MB on the rare occasion.

Comment: fine then.... @fractal5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i said in comments above after every recycle , progress value of downloading fields that are visible in ListView must be updated .by using some type of array like hashMap ,progress values and positions of downloading item must be cached in adapter class then at recycle time use them and update list Items . in this particular case after doing it , must call `notifyDataSetChanged()`  in main Thread of program and in asynctask in onProgressUpdate :

```
  @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    percentComplete.setText(progress[0].toString());
    yourListView.notifyDataSetChanged();//
}
```